# Using Substr in a While loop for multiple products

Tags: php, substring

I am trying to show only part of my items details and have implemented substr into my while loop. However it works for my first product, but my second product only shows the '...' and not the first 7 characters

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ 
    $id = $row["id"]; 
    $product_name = $row["product_name"]; 
    $price = $row["price"]; 
    $details = $row["details"]; 
    if (strlen($details) > 10){
        $details1 = substr($details, 0, 7) . '...';
    } else {
        $details1 = $details;
    }
    $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"])); 
    $dynamicList .= '<div class="contentImage"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id .'"><img src="images/stock_images/' . $id . '.png" alt="' . $product_name .'" width="136" height="97"></a></div> 
            <div class="contentDes"><strong>' . $product_name .'</strong><br> 
            Price: ¬£' . $price .'<br> 
                    ' . $details1 . '<br> 
                    <a href="product.php?id=' . $id .'">View Product</a></div>'; 
}
```

Comment: The code looks alright, what are the values for `details` from databse?

Comment: @SAVAFA they are "Here we have decking" and "Here we have a fence panel", when I use above code I get "Here we..." and "..." for my second product

Answer (score 0):

Either make this:

```
  if (strlen($details) > 7){
        $details1 = substr($details, 0, 7) . '...';
    }
```

OR

```
 if (strlen($details) > 10){
        $details1 = substr($details, 0, 10) . '...';
    }
```

Comment: I have this already in the code above, and as I mentioned in my original post, it works, but only for the first product. The second product only displays "..."